# DIV 'flex-box' elements extruding beyond border iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, flexbox

ok i have a problem that ive never seen before.
I have an h1 and a p tag with content, all wrapped in a div wiht class called .mainwrapper which is then wrapped again in another div with class .main to create a border effect. 

**CSS**

```
p
{
  font-family:Play;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;  
  margin:0 auto;
  font-size:22px;
}

h1
{
  font-family:Stardos Stencil;
  font-size:48px;
  width: 90%;  
  margin:0 auto;  

}
.main
{
display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
flex-direction: column;
padding-top:40px;
padding-bottom:40px;
z-index: 20;
width: 100vw;
right: 0;
left: 0;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
background:rgb(30,30,30);
color: white;
position: relative;
transition: visibility 2s, opacity 1s linear;
box-shadow:0 -8px 8px rgb(0,0,0);
}
.mainwrapper
{
display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
over-flow: contain;
flex-direction: column;
position: relative;
width: 90vw;
height: auto;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
margin:0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <div class="main">
    <div class="mainwrapper">
      <h1>About Us</h1>
      <br>
      <p>Based in Greeley, Colorado and Operating In and Around the Greater Wattenberg Shale and DJ Basin. We Specialize in BOP Stack Testing, BOP and Accumulator Service and Repair, Gate Valve Repair, Hydraulic  Torque Wrench Service, Production Completion and Much More. <a href="contact.php">Just Ask!</a> Pathfinder Pressure is a Veteran Owned and Operated Business, We bring Integrity and Experience to Every Drilling and/or Completion Operation.  Our Equipment is State of the Art, Thoughtfully Engineered, and Meticulously Maintained. We Arrive On Time, Ready to Work, with Safety as Our First Priority in Everything We Do. We Maintain a Flawless Safety Record with ZERO Recordable Incidents, That's a Record We Plan to Keep.</p><br>
    </div>
   </div>
```

i have the height of both div's set to auto so that that the elements are responsive. This works great on a desktop browser, but on my iphone 7 the paragraph content extrudes the bottom borders of both div's. I can fix this problem using media queries and setting the .mainwrappers height to something like 700px, but this isnt truly a 'responsive' approach as far as im concerned and wondering what, if anything, others have done to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Try setting `min-height: 0` on all flex items.

Answer (score 1):

Kellen Lester was correct in the comments below his answer. 
For anyone reading this, don't use display:flex-box for EVERY div. Safari iOS does not like it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test this unfortunately, but let me know if this works. Basically, all I only removed `flex-direction: column;` from `.main`, and added `flex: 1;`. I've only started using flexbox recently, and Safari has been a constant trouble maker. If it still doesn't work, try changing the display of `.main` to `inline-block`. Lastly, if you're still having no luck, try removing the height properties from `.mainwrapper` and `.main`. They shouldn't be needed.

```
p
{
  font-family:Play;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;  
  margin:0 auto;
  font-size:22px;
}

h1
{
  font-family:Stardos Stencil;
  font-size:48px;
  width: 90%;  
  margin:0 auto;  

}
.main
{
flex: 1;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
padding-top:40px;
padding-bottom:40px;
z-index: 20;
width: 100vw;
right: 0;
left: 0;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
background:rgb(30,30,30);
color: white;
position: relative;
transition: visibility 2s, opacity 1s linear;
box-shadow:0 -8px 8px rgb(0,0,0);
}
.mainwrapper
{
display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
over-flow: contain;
flex-direction: column;
position: relative;
width: 90vw;
height: auto;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: flex: 1; ?? what is this usually used for?

Comment: @KyleMathewJoeckel Since `main` does  not have a flex container, `flex:1` in this case does nothing, but when used properly, on a flex item, it makes the item to stretch and take the available space what's left of its parent

Comment: thanks, your right it does nothing but .main does in fact have a flex container. the 'body' of this page is set up as a simple div flex-box similar to these.

Comment: @KyleMathewJoeckel Sorry, I apologize, for some reason I was thinking you'd have multiple columns, but that obviously doesn't make sense, looking at your code. As I mentioned the flex display properties shouldn't be needed on `.main`. Not sure if that's the issue, but I suspect it's related to display or height. I'd be willing to test myself, but I don't have an iOS device.

Comment: No worries I'll try and those suggestions also, thanks

Comment: You were right. Main shouldn't have been a flexbox. Fixed every issue I was having. Thanks.

Comment: @KyleMathewJoeckel Cool! Glad you figured it out.